# authorize_resource not preventing access when it should?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have the following:

```rb
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_conversation_show, only: [:show]
  authorize_resource

  def show
  end

  private 
    def set_conversation_show
      @conversation = Conversation.where("sender_id = ?", current_user.id).find_by_id(params.fetch(:id))
    end
end
```

My understanding is that:

- Since a model instance (`@conversation`) is set in a `before_action`, `authorize_resource` should simply check to see if the `current_user` has access to that resource, and if not, deny access.

However, access is allowed....

When I change `authorize_resource` to `load_and_authorize_resource`, then access is denied as it should be.

Note: `authorize_resource` is the same as `load_and_authorize_resource` except it doesn't assume what what model instance should be loaded, but instead relies on there being one provided via a `before_action`. (more [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions)).

I prefer to use `authorize_resource` for that very reason - because it doesn't automatically assume the model instance it is to check permissions against.

So the question is, why isn't the above code working as expected and denying access?

#### For reference

The relevant `ability.rb`:

```rb
can [:show], [Conversation] do |conversation|
  conversation.sender_id == user.id
end
```